# Elastic search query making string match case insensitive

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

filterInputs.profileId = "d12";

```
var results = client
                                    .Search<StockBaseEntity>(s => s
                                    .Type("item")
                                    .Take(1000)
                                    .Filter(f => f
                                    .Bool(bb => bb
                                    .Must(ms =>
                                    {
                                        return
                                           !ms.Term("profileId", filterInputs.profileId)
                                    })))
                                    .Sort(so => so.OnField("sortScore").Ascending())
                                );
```

"profileId" can be in small or capitals or mixed. I want to return result irrespective of the case.

How can i do this?

Currently, its treating d123 different from D123.
OR da different from DA, different from dA.
(All these should be same).

How can i do this?

Comment: May you share index mapping? By `"profileId" can be in small or capitals or mixed` do you mean - value of `profileId` field can be in small or capitals or mixed?

Comment: yes. value of "profileId" in document can be small/capitals. Also the passed input filterInputs.profileId can also be in any case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `standard` analyzer for the field `profileId` (which I guess you are otherwise you wouldn't be asking this question), then the values are stored in lowercase in Elasticsearch index. You need to lowercase the value of `filterInputs.profileId` and pass it in the `Term()` filter.

```
var results = client.Search<StockBaseEntity>(s => s
    .Type("item")
    .Take(1000)
    .Filter(f => f
        .Bool(bb => bb
            .Must(ms => 
            { 
                return !ms.Term("profileId", filterInputs.profileId.ToLowerInvariant());
            })))
    .Sort(so => so.OnField("sortScore").Ascending()));
```

Comment: I dont know about analyzer since i am new to elastic search but the documents have "profileId" in capitals as well.

Comment: Even if you tried to index the field with capital letters, in the inverted index the value is lower-cased and stored. So if you also search for the lower-cased value, you should see results. Does my query work for you?

Comment: @bittusarkar worth mentioning `not_analyzed` fields and where one would like analyzed and not analyzed fields, `multi_fields` too